# Mongodb - automatically increment a field on daily

Tags: mongodb

I have the use case to increment a value by one on daily morning. Is there any way to do it without using scheduled trigger on the mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

```
let consider the dataCollection name is restaurants1=
{
  "address": { "building": "1007",

  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
.....
db.restaurants1.findAndModify({
    query: { "name" : "Morris Park Bake Shop" },
    update: { $inc: { "age": 1 } },
});
```

[look to this example](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/shell-methods/collection/db-collection-findAndModify.php)

Comment: No, I wanted mongodb to automatically increment a field value by 1 on daily basis. Is there any in-build property that can be define at field level? Say, I has the document - {"daysLeft":0}. It should be increment automatically on daily